# How to use thread pool in WebLogic 8?

Tags: java, multithreading, weblogic, threadpool, weblogic8.x

How is it possible to get/use/return a thread from an execute queue ( = thread pool) in WebLogic 8.1.6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, no, this is not possible, you can't get a thread directly. Instead, assign an execute queue to a Servlet, JSP, EJB, or RMI object.

> Weblogic let you assign an execute
>   queue to Servlets, JSPs, EJBs, and RMI
>   objects. In order to associate an
>   execute queue with a servlet (or JSP),
>   you need to specify the
>   `wl-dispatch-policy` initialization
>   parameter for the servlet (or JSP) in
>   the `web.xml` descriptor file. The
>   following code sample shows how to
>   assign the execute queue
>   `mySpecialQueue` to a JSP page:
>
> ```
> <!-- web.xml entry -->
> <servlet>
>     <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
>     <jsp-file>/critical.jsp</jsp-file>
>     <init-param>
>         <param-name>wl-dispatch-policy</param-name>
>         <param-value>mySpecialQueue</param-value>
>     </init-param>
> </servlet>
> ```
>
> In order to assign an execute queue to
>   an RMI object, you must specify the
>   -dispatchPolicy option when using Weblogic's RMI compiler (rmic). Here's
>   how you would assign the execute queue
>   `mySpecialQueue` to an RMI object:
>
> ```
> java weblogic.rmic -dispatchPolicy mySpecialQueue ...
>  In the same way, use the `-dispatchPolicy` option when invoking
> ```
>
> Weblogic's EJB compiler to assign the
>   execute queute to an EJB. Weblogic's
>   EJB compiler implicitly passes the
>   `-dipatchPolicy` argument to the
>   underlying RMI compiler. In Weblogic
>   8.1, use the `dispatch-policy` element in the EJB's `weblogic-ejb-jar.xml`
>   descriptor to set the execute queue:
>
> ```
> <!-- weblogic-ejb-jar.xml descriptor -->
> <weblogic-enterprise-bean>
>     <ejb-name>myEJB</ejb-name>
>     ...
>     <dispatch-policy>myEJBQueue</dispatch-policy>
> </weblogic-enterprise-bean>
> ```
>
> Custom execute queues are supported
>   for all EJB types - session beans,
>   entity beans, and MDBs.
>
> At runtime, Weblogic allocates worker
>   threads for your servlets, JSPs, EJBs,
>   and RMI objects from their configured
>   execute queues, thereby guaranteeing
>   that selected objects in your
>   application have access to a fixed
>   number of server threads. For those
>   objects for which no execute queue is
>   assigned, the threads will be
>   allocated from the server's default
>   execute queue.